# Sort lines in a file according to one column

Tags: matlab

I have a text file containing multiple lines, each consisting of strings and floats,

```
%s1 %s1 %s1 %f1 %f1 %f1
%s2 %s2 %s2 %f2 %f2 %f2
```

In my function, I need to sort those lines according to one of the floats in a single column, let's say to switch row 2 for row 1 if f2 < f1. I know I can use

```
sort
```

but I don't know how to carry the rest of the line to the new spot.

Comment: Have you already pulled the strings and floats into Matlab vectors? Or is it part of your problem?

Comment: No, I can extract the data from a file on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) function is designed to handle this and works for cell arrays:

> `sortrows(X,COL)` sorts the matrix based on the columns specified in the
>       vector `COL`.

Say you have your datatable `T` formatted as a cell. For example, this random data:

```
>> T = [mat2cell(char(randi(26,4,3)+64),ones(4,1),ones(3,1)) num2cell(rand(4,3))]
T = 
    'W'    'M'    'D'    [0.5795]    [0.1008]    [0.1439]
    'Z'    'X'    'S'    [0.1030]    [0.5029]    [0.3192]
    'R'    'I'    'U'    [0.3553]    [0.4873]    [0.4491]
    'L'    'I'    'U'    [0.9389]    [0.7817]    [0.0499]
```

To sort according to column #4 in ascending order:

```
>> TSortedCol4 = sortrows(T,4)
TSortedCol4 = 
    'Z'    'X'    'S'    [0.1030]    [0.5029]    [0.3192]
    'R'    'I'    'U'    [0.3553]    [0.4873]    [0.4491]
    'W'    'M'    'D'    [0.5795]    [0.1008]    [0.1439]
    'L'    'I'    'U'    [0.9389]    [0.7817]    [0.0499]
```

---

If you need to get your data into the format of `T` above from a text file, you can do the following to read and reformat it:

```
fid = fopen('testtable.txt','r');
Tin = textscan(fid, '%q %q %q %f %f %f'); % each column has a cell
strcols=cellfun(@iscell,Tin);
T = [Tin{strcols} num2cell([Tin{~strcols}])]; % each item has a cell
fclose(fid);
```

As in your example, the columns are delimited by white space. The strings can include spaces if double quotes are used in the text file because of the `%q` format specifier.

Comment: Thank you, this has been very usefu.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two vectors x1 and x2. You want to sort by x1.

```
[sorted_version_1, I] = sort(x1);
sorted_version_2 = x1(I);
% sorted_version_1 == sorted_version_2, both sorts of x2

sorted_x2 = x2(I)
```

If you have strings, the data structure may be different and you might have to use {} instead of () to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

To parse the strings and floats you can use `textscan(fileid, '%s %s %s %f %f %f')`. It returns a cell array. The float data matrix you need can be formed using the last three cells of the cell array.

You can then use `sort(matrix, 2)` to sort the rows.

If you want to rewrite the textfile, then overwrite on it the processed data. To write to a file you can use `fprintf(fileid, '%s %s %s %f %f %f', elements_of_a_row)`